# How to make card deck list with no repeatable cards in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some problem with card deck in Unity.
I get card from directory using *AssetBundle* and put them in *Array*. Then using cycle I add card from *array* to *CardList*.

In the unity directory Cards order like this:

> card_1, card_2, card_3, card_4......card_52

Here is part of this script:

```
public void InstanatiateDeck(string cardBundlePath)
{
    AssetBundle cardBundle = BundleSingleton.Instance.LoadBundle(DirectoryUtility.ExternalAssets() + cardBundlePath);
    string[] nameArray = cardBundle.GetAllAssetNames();
    for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.Length; ++i)
    {
        GameObject cardInstance = (GameObject)Instantiate(_cardPrefab);
        Card card = cardInstance.GetComponent<Card>();

        card.gameObject.name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nameArray[i]);
        card.TexturePath = nameArray[ i ];
        card.SourceAssetBundlePath = cardBundlePath;
        card.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 10, 0);
        card.FaceValue = StringToFaceValue(card.gameObject.name);
        CardList.Add(card);
    }
}
```

But using this script the cards in *CardList* order similarly directory order like this:

> Element 0.card_1, Element 1.card_2, Element 2.card_3, Element 3.card_4...... Element 51.card_52

If I add Random.Range in this script, I get repeatable values in my *CardList*

```
public void InstanatiateDeck(string cardBundlePath)
{
    AssetBundle cardBundle = BundleSingleton.Instance.LoadBundle(DirectoryUtility.ExternalAssets() + cardBundlePath);
    string[] nameArray = cardBundle.GetAllAssetNames();
    for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.Length; ++i)
    {
        GameObject cardInstance = (GameObject)Instantiate(_cardPrefab);
        Card card = cardInstance.GetComponent<Card>();
        int random = Random.Range(0, nameArray.Length);
        card.gameObject.name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nameArray[random]);
        card.TexturePath = nameArray[ random ];
        card.SourceAssetBundlePath = cardBundlePath;
        card.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 10, 0);
        card.FaceValue = StringToFaceValue(card.gameObject.name);
        CardList.Add(card);
    }
}
```

How can modify script to put cards in *CardList* by **random order** without repeatable values?

for example

> Element 0.card_7, Element 1.card_50, Element 2.card_24, Element 3.card_12...... Element 51.card_9

Thanks guys and excuse my poor English

Comment: What type is `CardList` ?

Comment: List<Card> CaldList = new List<Card>();

Comment: My comment was irrevelant, I misread your question

Comment: make a copy of the initial list, and randomize it,..

Comment: Thank u. I need to think how to apply it to my script

Comment: use the first version in your question and after your for loop, shuffle it

Comment: I add `private static Random rng = new Random();  

public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}` in another script and after my for loop add `scriptname.Shuffle` but int unity 2019 `rng.Next` take an error